# How to efficiently insert elements after another known (by key or pointer) element in a PHP array?

Tags: php, performance, arrays

Given an array:

```
$a = array(
    'abc',
    123,
    'k1'=>'v1',
    'k2'=>'v2',
    78,
    'tt',
    'k3'=>'v3'
);
```

With its internal pointer on one of its elements, how do I insert an element after the current element?
And how do I insert an element after a key-known element, say 'k1'?

Performance Care~

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could do it by splitting your array using `array_keys` and `array_values`, then splice them both, then combine them again.

```
$insertKey = 'k1';

$keys = array_keys($arr);
$vals = array_values($arr);

$insertAfter = array_search($insertKey, $keys) + 1;

$keys2 = array_splice($keys, $insertAfter);
$vals2 = array_splice($vals, $insertAfter);

$keys[] = "myNewKey";
$vals[] = "myNewValue";

$newArray = array_merge(array_combine($keys, $vals), array_combine($keys2, $vals2));
```

Comment: There is a one-off error in this solution. It can be corrected by adding $insertAfter++; before the array_splice() calls.

Answer (score 6):

I found a great answer [here](http://eosrei.net/articles/2011/11/php-arrayinsertafter-arrayinsertbefore) that works really well. I want to document it, so others on SO can find it easily:

```
/*
 * Inserts a new key/value before the key in the array.
 *
 * @param $key
 *   The key to insert before.
 * @param $array
 *   An array to insert in to.
 * @param $new_key
 *   The key to insert.
 * @param $new_value
 *   An value to insert.
 *
 * @return
 *   The new array if the key exists, FALSE otherwise.
 *
 * @see array_insert_after()
 */
function array_insert_before($key, array &$array, $new_key, $new_value) {
  if (array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
    $new = array();
    foreach ($array as $k => $value) {
      if ($k === $key) {
        $new[$new_key] = $new_value;
      }
      $new[$k] = $value;
    }
    return $new;
  }
  return FALSE;
}

/*
 * Inserts a new key/value after the key in the array.
 *
 * @param $key
 *   The key to insert after.
 * @param $array
 *   An array to insert in to.
 * @param $new_key
 *   The key to insert.
 * @param $new_value
 *   An value to insert.
 *
 * @return
 *   The new array if the key exists, FALSE otherwise.
 *
 * @see array_insert_before()
 */
function array_insert_after($key, array &$array, $new_key, $new_value) {
  if (array_key_exists ($key, $array)) {
    $new = array();
    foreach ($array as $k => $value) {
      $new[$k] = $value;
      if ($k === $key) {
        $new[$new_key] = $new_value;
      }
    }
    return $new;
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Useful code, I just modified it to add value in case key does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use internal array pointer to insert elements.

There's `array_splice` which can insert/remove/replace elements and subarrays, but it's intended for integer-indexed arrays.

I'm afraid you'll have to rebuild the array to insert element (except cases where you want to insert first/last element) or use separate integer-indexed array for holding keys in the order you want.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking doubly linked list would be ideal for this task.

There is a built-in implementation of that since PHP 5.3, called [SplDoublyLinkedList](http://ee.php.net/manual/en/class.spldoublylinkedlist.php) and since PHP 5.5 it also has [add method](http://php.net/manual/en/spldoublylinkedlist.add.php), which allows adding/inserting values in the middle.

Comment: Actually, [SplDoublyLinkedList](http://ee.php.net/manual/en/class.spldoublylinkedlist.php) allows for insertion on desired index with [SplDoublyLinkedList::add method](http://php.net/manual/en/spldoublylinkedlist.add.php) since this [pull request](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/288). I don't know when this was added since documentation doesn't mention in which php version this was changed.

Comment: It actually does mentions the version: (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0) - I have updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

This way is fine for new values without keys. You can not insert value with a key, and numeric indexes will be 'reset' as 0 to N-1.

```
$keys = array_keys($a);
$index = array_flip($keys);

$key = key($a); //current element
//or 
$key = 'k1';

array_splice($a, $index[$key] + 1, 0, array('value'));
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice function that would help you here: https://gist.github.com/scribu/588429