# Problem with an associative array not sorting correctly

Tags: php, associative-array, sorting

Ok, I have an array set up like so:

```
$buttons = array(
    'home' => array(
        'title' => $txt['home'],
        'href' => $scripturl,
        'show' => true,
        'sub_buttons' => array(
        ),
        'is_last' => $context['right_to_left'],
    ),
    'help' => array(
        'title' => $txt['help'],
        'href' => $scripturl . '?action=help',
        'show' => true,
        'sub_buttons' => array(
        ),
    ),
);
```

Than I call a function after this is loaded to add some more buttons to it and have it sorted correctly, like this:

```
$buttons = load_dream_menu($buttons);
```

The load_dream_menu function looks like this:

```
function load_dream_menu($menu_buttons)
{
    global $smcFunc, $user_info, $scripturl, $context;

    $request = $smcFunc['db_query']('', '
        SELECT *
        FROM {db_prefix}dp_dream_menu
        ORDER BY id_button ASC',
        array(
        )
    );

    $new_menu_buttons = array();

    while ($row = $smcFunc['db_fetch_assoc']($request))
    {
        $permissions = explode(',', $row['permissions']);

        $dp_temp_menu = array(
            'title' => $row['name'],
            'href' => ($row['target'] == 'forum' ? $scripturl : '') . $row['link'],
            'show' => (array_intersect($user_info['groups'], $permissions)) && ($row['status'] == 'active' || (allowedTo('admin_forum') && $row['status'] == 'inactive')),
            'target' => $row['target'],
            'active_button' => false,
        );

        foreach ($menu_buttons as $area => $info)
        {
            if ($area == $row['parent'] && $row['position'] == 'before')
                $new_menu_buttons[$row['slug']] = $dp_temp_menu;

            $new_menu_buttons[$area] = $info;

            if ($area == $row['parent'] && $row['position'] == 'after')
                $new_menu_buttons[$row['slug']] = $dp_temp_menu;

            if ($area == $row['parent'] && $row['position'] == 'child_of')
                $new_menu_buttons[$row['parent']]['sub_buttons'][$row['slug']] = $dp_temp_menu;

            if ($row['position'] == 'child_of' && isset($info['sub_buttons']) && array_key_exists($row['parent'], $info['sub_buttons']))
                $new_menu_buttons[$area]['sub_buttons'][$row['parent']]['sub_buttons'][$row['slug']] = $dp_temp_menu;
        }
    }

    if (!empty($new_menu_buttons))
        $menu_buttons = $new_menu_buttons;

    return $menu_buttons;
}
```

Ok, so it manages to sort the first one but doesn't sort the other one's after that?  Is there something I'm supposed to use within the foreach loop of the load_dream_menu function?  Something like using `reset()`, but that doesn't seem to work either.  What am I doing wrong here?  Please someone help me.

So basically, I check the database, than I loop through all available menu items and add them into another array, than at the end, I set the original array ($buttons) to the newly created array.  Shouldn't this work?  Here is where I do this within load_dream_menu() function:

```
        foreach ($menu_buttons as $area => $info)
        {
            if ($area == $row['parent'] && $row['position'] == 'before')
                $new_menu_buttons[$row['slug']] = $dp_temp_menu;

            $new_menu_buttons[$area] = $info;

            if ($area == $row['parent'] && $row['position'] == 'after')
                $new_menu_buttons[$row['slug']] = $dp_temp_menu;

            if ($area == $row['parent'] && $row['position'] == 'child_of')
                $new_menu_buttons[$row['parent']]['sub_buttons'][$row['slug']] = $dp_temp_menu;

            if ($row['position'] == 'child_of' && isset($info['sub_buttons']) && array_key_exists($row['parent'], $info['sub_buttons']))
                $new_menu_buttons[$area]['sub_buttons'][$row['parent']]['sub_buttons'][$row['slug']] = $dp_temp_menu;
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do... If I get this right, you want to insert the new buttons **before**, **after**, or as a **child** of the parent? If so the insert logic is wrong; you might want to look at [array_slice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want to do, what is wrong with the logic of it?

Comment: But how to use `array_slice` on associative arrays?  Is it possible?

Comment: For a start your first pass in the foreach loop (first row) will populate new_menu_buttons with all of the old buttons. After that you lose the ability to prepend or append since there is no way to insert before/after in the array.

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not have functions out of the box to insert elements after or before an indexed key.

The current problem with your function is that when you read the first row, you will put back all the previous menu buttons into the new menu buttons. After that, there is no way to insert before or after, short of rebuilding the array. I would suggest writing helper functions like

```
insert_before(array, key, value)
{
    // Splice array in two at key, keeping key on the right side
    // Append new value on the left tail
    // Glue both arrays into a new array
    // Return new array
}
insert_after(array, key, value)
{
    // Symmetric with right & left switched
}
```

Then you can use those functions in your sorting routine.

I found [this helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286853/how-to-efficiently-insert-elements-after-another-known-by-key-or-pointer-elemen) about efficient inserts in PHP arrays.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: This is great, but can you give me an example of how to do this before and/or after?